# Does the wavelength/frequency of light affect the intensity distribution of a two-slit interference pattern?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light

Using the expression $\Delta y= \lambda L /d$, I understand that an increase in wavelength would increase the distance between the adjacent maximas/minimas but am wondering if the actual intensity of the pattern changes. i.e an increase/decrease of the height of the peaks on a position vs intensity graph? Do the fringes appear brighter or darker?

Hopefully that makes sense^ sorry this is only my second post.